# How can I get my two divs to align with bootstrap?

Tags: html, css, twitter-bootstrap

I have a bootstrap input that requires another div to the right of it but it won't seem to align with the code I'm using.

HTML (With bootstrap & fontawesome)

```
<div class="row">
<div id="mobNum" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-xs-6"> 
<span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20px"><i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i></span><input id="mobile" class="form-control requiredClass" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number.."/></div>
    <div id="showDivMobile" class="showDivClass needData" style="col-xs-6">
         <i class="fa fa-asterisk showCSS " aria-hidden="true"></i>vv<br/></div>
</div>
```

And my fiddle: http://jsfiddle.net/JLjjK/1350/

Comment: `style="col-xs-6"` ?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The issue is with this code from bootstrap

`<div id="mobNum" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-xs-6">`

CSS rule for input-group

```
.input-group[class*=col-] {
    float: none;                  // this is the problem
    padding-right: 0;
    padding-left: 0;
}
```

It should be `float:left` So write a inline style to make it float left and it should be fine.

Also another issue is with `style="col-xs-6"` it must go in to `class`

Here is a **[working fiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/JLjjK/1351/)**.

---

Changes done

`<div id="mobNum" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-xs-6" style="float:left">`

and

`<div id="showDivMobile" class="showDivClass needData col-xs-6" style="">`

Answer (score 2):

When using Bootstrap, it is a good practice to put your layout related classes (*col*s and *row*s) in separate divs elements; These classes should not be present in other elements like input-groups.

In your case, when you combine input-group with col-xs-6, it overrides the float attribute and breaks your layout, placing the divs on two separate lines.

Try separating them like this:

```
<div class="row">
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="mobNum" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm">...</div>
  </div>
  <div class="col-xs-6">
    <div id="showDivMobile" class="showDivClass needData">...</div>
  </div>
</div>
```

Hope this helps!

Answer (score 1):

```
<div style="display:flex;">
  <div id="mobNum" class="input-group margin-bottom-sm col-xs-6"> 
    <span class="input-group-addon" style="width:20px">
     <i class="fa fa-phone-square" aria-hidden="true"></i>
    </span>
    <input id="mobile" class="form-control requiredClass" type="text" placeholder="Mobile Number.."/>
  </div>
  <div id="showDivMobile" class="showDivClass needData col-xs-6">
   <i class="fa fa-asterisk showCSS " aria-hidden="true"></i>vv<br/>
  </div>
</div>
```